# Uninstall AnkhSVN from VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

I want to remove AnkhSVN from my VS2010 install, but find that the Uninstall option is grayed out when I navigate to TOOLS*/Extensions and Updates.

Starting Visual Studio 2012 as Administrator and unselecting AnkhSVN as the source control provider did not enable the Uninstall option.

**I'm not shouting TOOLS, just trying to get in the spirit of the new UI :-)*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AnkhSVN apparently cannot be disabled or uninstalled from within Visual Studio 2012.

Do the following instead:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio.
- Run the AnkhSVN uninstaller.

*Note: I ran the uninstaller in Revo Uninstaller, and there were no left-over artifacts (files, registry entries).*

After uninstalling AnkhSVN, you may find that some of your projects still have source control binding information in the .csproj file.  I had a solution with 10 projects, and only 8 of them had this problem (all projects were controlled by AnkhSVN... not sure why not all had the issue).  In that case, you will get the error:

> The project 'X' is under source control.  An error occurred registering this project with source control.  It is recommended that you not make any changes to this project.

I was able to resolve this by editing the .csproj files in a text editor and removing the following lines:

```
<SccProjectName>Svn</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>Svn</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>Svn</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SubversionScc</SccProvider>
```

Comment: Visual Studio will offer the option of removing these lines when you open the solution. I would recommend just doing this as it is easier than doing this by hand.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to disconnect the project (File->Subversion->Change Source Control) while AnkhSVN is still installed, but the result is identical.

Answer (score 8):

I used

`Windows > Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a Program > AnkhSVN.`

Seems to work with no hassle for me. VS2012 was not open during the uninstallation.

Comment: Still works this way today, with uninstalling the latest AnkhSVN from VS2017.